# Problem with Component.Apex.PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I Need create a Dynamic Component in Controller Class, have following code:

```
public class CtrlPageBlockTable {
    public List<Account> lstAccount { get; set; }

    public CtrlPageBlockTable(){
        lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        lstAccount = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
    }

    public Component.Apex.PageBlockTable getDynamicBlockTable(){
        Component.Apex.PageBlockTable table = new Component.Apex.PageBlockTable(var='acc');
        table.value = lstAccount;

        Component.Apex.Column col = new Component.Apex.Column( headerValue='Link');
        Component.Apex.OutputLink link = new Component.Apex.OutputLink();
        link.expressions.value='/'+'{!acc.Id}';
        Component.Apex.OutputText text = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
        text.expressions.value='{!acc.Name}';
        link.childComponents.add(text);
        col.childComponents.add(link);
        table.childComponents.add(col);

        return table;
    }
}
```

VisualForce Page throws following exception:
[image]

This is VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="CtrlPageBlockTable">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Test Dynamic Component">
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!dynamicBlockTable}"  />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it will fix your problem, but I would expect that instead of assigning the list value in Apex:

```
table.value = lstAccount;
```

the Visualforce expression should be setup:

```
table.expressions.value='{!lstAccount}';
```

so that you are creating the direct equivalent of:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAccount}" var="acc">
```

But having looked in the docs maybe the two are equivalent; worth a quick try though.

Comment: great! this working for me!